# How do we use the shape-outside property with CSS Grid?

Tags: html, css

I've been tinkering around with the `shape-outside` property trying to get my text to go around a `div`.  I'm positioning the elements with css grid and have come to discover it doesn't seem to work at all no mater what I try to do.  Here's the html I have in my template file.

```css
.contentShell{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(22, 1fr);
    grid-template-rows: repeat(22, 1fr);
}

.descriptionAreaB{
    grid-area: 4/1/23/23;
    background-color: palevioletred;
    /*display: grid;*/
    display: block;
    /*float: left;*/
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: var(--smallText);
    /*word-wrap: normal;*/
}

.titleAreaB{
    grid-area: 1/1/8/13;
    background-color:peachpuff;
    /*display: block;*/
    display: grid;
    float: left;
    height: auto;
    width: 50%;
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: var(--articleText);
    shape-outside: inset(100%, 100%, 100%, 100%, 30px);
    -webkit-shape-outside: inset(100%, 100%, 100%, 100%, 30px);
    /*align-items: center;
    justify-items: center;*/
}
```

```html
<section class="contentShell">


    <div class="titleAreaB"><h2>Some long title blah blah blah something</h2></div>


    <p class="descriptionAreaB">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, incidunt fugit odit et impedit esse suscipit. Reprehenderit, blanditiis voluptatibus minus consectetur, ratione aspernatur similique soluta quis perferendis ipsam consequatur inventore.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut modi, blanditiis voluptas eligendi doloremque ut magnam enim cum explicabo repudiandae expedita quod fugit totam soluta harum? Ipsum rem ab perferendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum consectetur, nostrum veritatis, fugiat atque blanditiis reiciendis praesentium expedita odit mollitia vitae at aperiam quasi cum enim quae odio ipsum dicta!
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Nostrum, incidunt fugit odit et impedit esse suscipit. Reprehenderit, blanditiis voluptatibus minus consectetur, ratione aspernatur similique soluta quis perferendis ipsam consequatur inventore.
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Aut modi, blanditiis voluptas eligendi doloremque ut magnam enim cum explicabo repudiandae expedita quod fugit totam soluta harum? Ipsum rem ab perferendis? Lorem ipsum dolor sit, amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum consectetur, nostrum veritatis, fugiat atque blanditiis reiciendis praesentium expedita odit mollitia vitae at aperiam quasi cum enim quae odio ipsum dicta!
    </p>


</section>
```

When I change the `.contentShell` to `display: block` the elements behave as expected, but with `display: grid` it just layers over the heading.  Is there something else we need to do to make this work or is there something under the hood that prevents us from using these two things together?

Comment: Shape outside requires the element to be floated which cannot happen to children of a Css-grid

Comment: you don't even need shape-outside because the value your are using is invalid anyway. So only float will do the job

Comment: @TemaniAfif what do you mean I don't need `shape-outside`?  Is there a way to get the text to flow around the container without that property while using css grid?

Comment: to have something flow around something you need float and this will never ever work with CSS grid and flexbox so simply forget the idea. And by using a basic float here you don't even need shap-outside.

Answer (score -3):

The shape-outside property is used to define the shape that the adjacent inline content may wrap around. It can be used to define complex shapes including images that can be used to wrap text around instead of simple boxes.
shape-outside:  |  |  | none |  initial | inherit
for example: shape-outside: circle(25%);